# During an instrument approach, what are the obstruction clearance given?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach

I was wondering wether each segments of the approach has different minimum obstruction clearance? (E.g. initial, intermediate and final) From both terrain and man made obstacles.

If possible i would like it to be from ICAO, hence PANS-OPS. But any TERPS answers i would happily accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each segment of the approach has different MOC (Minimum Obstacle Clearance). Below I have quoted the MOC from ICAO DOC 8168 Volume II for each of the different segments of the approach.

Initial segment (Part I - Section 4, Chapter 3.3.4):

> The obstacle clearance in the initial approach primary area shall be a minimum of **300 m (984 ft)**. In the secondary area,
>   300 m (984 ft) of obstacle clearance shall be provided at the inner edge, reducing linearly to zero at the outer edge.

Intermediate segment (Part I - Section 4, Chapter 4.3.2.1):

> A minimum of **150 m (492 ft)** of obstacle clearance shall be provided in the primary area of the
>   intermediate approach segment. In the secondary area, 150 m (492 ft) of obstacle clearance shall be provided at the
>   inner edge, reducing to zero at the outer edge.

Final segment, for non-precision straight-in approaches without vertical guidance (Part I - Section 4, Chapter 5.4.3.1):

> The OCA/H for a straight-in, non-precision approach where the angle between the track and the extended runway
>   centre line does not exceed 5 degrees shall provide the following minimum obstacle clearance (MOC) over the
>   obstacles in the final approach area:
>   a) **75 m (246 ft)** with FAF; and
>   b) **90 m (295 ft)** without FAF.

Note that precision approaches and approaches with vertical guidance (ILS, LPV, LNAV/VNAV etc.) do not have a fixed MOC, and the obstacle clearance is calculated using more advanced methods.

Initial missed approach segment (Part I, Section 4, Chapter 6.2.1.3):

> Obstacle clearance in the initial phase. In the initial missed approach area, the minimum obstacle
>   clearance shall be **the same as for the last part of the final approach area** except where the extension of the intermediate
>   missed approach surface backwards towards the missed approach point requires less clearance. (See Figures I-4-6-4
>   and I-4-6-5.)

Intermediate missed approach segment (Part I, Section 4, Chapter 6.2.2.3.1):

> In the intermediate missed approach phase, the minimum obstacle clearance shall be **30 m (98 ft)** in the
>   primary area, and in the secondary area the minimum obstacle clearance shall be 30 m (98 ft) at the inner edge,
>   reducing linearly to zero at the outer edge.

Final missed approach segment:

> In the final missed approach phase of a straight missed approach the minimum obstacle clearance shall
>   be **50 m (164 ft) (Cat H, 40 m (132 ft))** in the primary area, reducing linearly to zero at the outer edge of the secondary
>   area.

Figure I-4-6-4 and I-4-6-5:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [FAA lays this out in Order 8260.3c](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/faa_order_8260.3c.pdf) the three main relevant sections for requirements, level flight and climbing/decent segments are:

> **2-1-2. Required Obstacle Clearance (ROC).** This order specifies the minimum measure of obstacle clearance considered by the FAA to supply
>   a satisfactory level of vertical protection. The validity of the
>   protection is dependent, in part, on assumed aircraft performance. In
>   the case of TERPS, it is assumed that aircraft will perform within
>   certification requirements.

...

> **2-1-3. Level OCS.** The level OCS concept is applicable to “level
>   flight” segments. These segments are level flight operations intended
>   for en route, STAR, feeder, initial, intermediate, and NPA final
>   approach segments. A single ROC value is applied over the length of
>   the segment. These values were determined through testing and
>   observation of aircraft and pilot performance in various flight
>   conditions. Typical ROC values are: 1000 feet (2000 over designated
>   mountainous terrain) for en route, STAR, and feeder segments, 1000
>   feet for initial segments, 500 feet for intermediate segments, and
>   250-500 feet for final segments.

...

> **2-1-4. Sloping OCS.** The method of applying ROC, in segments dedicated
>   to descending on a glidepath or climbing in a departure or missed
>   approach segment, requires a different obstacle clearance concept than
>   the level OCS because the ROC value must vary throughout the segment.
>   The value of ROC near the runway is relatively small and increases
>   throughout the segment.

The document is lengthy and lays out various formulas and charts, to keep form copying the whole thing here please [reference the document directly for anything more specific.](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/faa_order_8260.3c.pdf)